# Setting value to textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myText = $('#myTextBox').val() + '<span id="caret_pos_holder"></span>';
$('#myTextBox').val(myText);
console.log($('#myTextBox').val());
```

In the console log, there is no `< span >` tag.
Why isn't the value of the textbox set to it?

Comment: works perfectly fine here http://jsfiddle.net/GPCks/

Comment: Works for me too. Are you sure you have a tag on your page that looks something like `<input id="myTextBox">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector like this `$('textarea#myTextBox').val()`

You can see result in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDT8C/1/).